# How can we stop repeated calls in componentDidUpdate() lifecycle of a class based component, like we do in useEffect hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component, react-lifecycle, react-lifecycle-hooks, react-class-based-component

```
    useEffect(()=>{
        fetch(`${BASE_URL}/requested_url`)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(json => setData(json))
      }, []);
```

*When I used a class based component, I had to use a state boolean to specify when to start fetch and stop... Something very weird that I tried to get the work done, but I am still curious to know if we can stop a repeated call of request in componentDidUpdate() lifecycle method also.*

```
    componentDidUpdate() {
        if (this.state.show2) {
          return fetch(`${BASE_URL}/requested_url`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => setState({
              data: json,
              show2: false
            }))
        }
        return;
      }
```

*I know that this is not the correct way of doing a request call from a lifecycle. Also don't judge me for this... So, please tell me if anyone can help me do this correctly, or is it legitimate to do this...*

Comment: componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {} - you can use prevState param, do determine is state changed or not . For example if (prevState.show2 !== this.state.show2) {// make your request}

Comment: you should create some condition at which you do request

Answer (score 0):

The second property in `useEffect` is a dependency array. Basically, any external variable used in the effect needs to be put in there because the function will only run when they change value.

```
  useEffect(()=>{
    if (show2)
      fetch(`${BASE_URL}/requested_url`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => setData(json))
  }, [show2]);
```

Comment: we can't use Hook in class based component right ? as QA is mentioned he want to archive it in Class based component.